# recibir datos con $_SESSION PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, php7

Bueno tengo dos paginas una llamada sesion.php y la otra perfil.php lo que trato de hacer es que al momento de que el usuario inicie sesión (obviamente ya comprando que existe en la base de datos) pues este sea redireccionado a su perfil de usuario en el cual aparecen todos sus datos. Hasta ahí creo que ya explique lo que trato de hacer, pero la forma en que lo hago es usando $_SESSION de esta forma:

Sesion.php

```
<?php
  
// Datos para conectar a la base de datos.

  
// Crear conexión con la base de datos.
$conn = new mysqli($nombreServidor, $nombreUsuario, $passwordBaseDeDatos, $nombreBaseDeDatos);
   

session_start();
// Obtengo los datos cargados en el formulario de login.
$usuraio = $_POST['username'];
$clave = $_POST['password'];

// Consulta segura para evitar inyecciones SQL.
$q = "SELECT COUNT(*) as contar from usuarios where correo = '$usuraio' and passwordd = '$clave' ";
$consulta = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

if($array['contar']>0){
  $_SESSION['username']=$usuraio;
  header('Location: perfil.php ');
    //die();
}else{
    echo "Datos incorrectos";
}
?>
```

y perfil.php que se supone que deberia recibir la variable del usuario que esta accediendo en este caso 'username':

```
<?php

session_start();
$usuraio = $_SESSION['username'];

echo"<h1>Welcome $usuraio</h1> ";

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Creo que existen mejores formas de hacerlo, de ser así podrían solo darme una guía de como buscarlo o si son gustosos de explicármelo. Gracias :D

Comment: Asumo que esas credenciales de acceso no son las reales, cierto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo que espero que los datos de acceso que muestras no sean los reales, y en cuanto a la pregunta yo lo hago de esta forma.
Lo primero es que por lo menos filtres las variables POST para mejorar un poco la seguridad.

```
$usuraio = $_POST["username"];
$usuraio = addslashes($usuraio);
$usuraio = strip_tags($usuraio);

$clave = $_POST["password"];
$clave = addslashes($clave);
$clave = strip_tags($clave);
```

Luego realizo la consulta

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$usuraio' and 
 password='$clave'";
 $respuesta = $conn->query($sql);
```

Si el usuario y contraseña no existen no los dejo entrar y si por el contrario existen  entonces lo que hago allí es que inicio sesión y redirecciono

```
if ($respuesta->num_rows === 0) {
echo "Datos incorrectos";
}else{
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"] = $usuraio;
header('Location: perfil.php ')
}
```

Y por último donde la voy a recibir en tu caso perfil.php mantengo la sesión abierta y llamo las variables que necesito.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<h3>Bienvenido: <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></h3>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo intenta esto

tu codigo

```
<?php
session_start();
$usuraio = $_SESSION['username'];

echo"<h1>Welcome $usuraio</h1> ";

?>
```

cambialo por eso

```
<?php

session_start();
$usuraio = $_SESSION['username'];

echo"<h1>Welcome echo $usuraio</h1> ";

?>
```